# How send metafield or text from Woo cart page to ready Order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I need send text data from woocommerc cart page to ready order - by cart items data.

1) Set text to metafield in first product when click button GO TO CHECKOUT at CART PAGE
2) Get this metafield in Order data when order complited.

1) ADD METAFIELD TO CART ITEM .

```
$cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
foreach( $cart as $cart_item_id=>$cart_item ) {
    $cart_item['my_metafield'] = "text";
    WC()->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_id] = $cart_item;
}
WC()->cart->set_session();
```

2) GET METAFIELD FROM ORDER ITEMS

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_complited' , 'get_my_metafield' , 10 , 1 );

function get_my_metafield ( $order ){

     How get ['my_metafield'] ? Product don`t have 'my_metafield'

}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? What did you try?

Comment: Kindly but your question is totally unclear. You should try to give more context and reword your question (Why do you need that? for what? is this need to be order item meta data or order meta data?)…

Answer (score 0):

This function add Cart items metafield to Order items metafiels

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', function( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order )
{
    if ( isset( $values['my_metafield'] ) )     {
            $item->add_meta_data( "my_metafield", $values['my_metafield'] , true );
    }
}, 10, 4 );
```